# Structured Ways to choose Type I and Type II Error Rates

Tags: error, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

This question is perhaps more philosophical in nature than statistical.

I'm working in a setting where the differences between groups are small and sample sizes are large. Nonetheless, it is often time-consuming to accrue the necessary number of individuals to reach traditional sample size requirements with a power analysis because the differences between groups are small and variances are large. Coming from an academic setting, 5% significance and 90% power were common. It is, however, quite likely that having a 5% significance may be too low.

In choosing sample sizes for a two-sample t-test with equal variances, one of my colleagues suggested increasing the level of significance from 5% up to 20% to decrease the required sample size in a randomized trial. While this approach would indeed lower the sample size, it seems a rather ad-hoc way to avoid the problem of long accrual times.

What are some structured methods for choosing Type I and Type II Errors? It is not that much worse to have a Type I Error than it is to have a Type II Error in our context, so perhaps setting the two equal (or roughly equal) may be a way to ameliorate long accruals. Having a reference to call upon would give me more confidence about choosing error rates.

Comment: There might be some paper out there that has a fitting framework, but I don't know about it. Most applied papers I have read use a 5% significance level without any justification, other than: it's the standard.

Comment: @Repmat My experience puts me in a similar camp. 5% significance was usually chosen with little regard, but I'm aware that some fields use different standards of evidence (physics has the 5-sigma rule, for example). The question is to determine if there's some structured guidelines for how to choose level of significance and power, given a careful weighing of the type I and type II losses.

Comment: There's some discussion of the tradeoff [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/errortypes.html) (toward the bottom of the link, just under the last diagram). One can weight up the costs/chances of incorrect decisions (& perhaps benefits of correct ones) or more formally take a decision-theory approach (presumably frequentist, but you could even look at it more as a Bayesian I guess). There's a brief mention of minimizing expected loss under Bayesian and frequentist points of view on slides 24-25 [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~xial/Teaching/2013F/slides/14-hypothesistesting.pdf)